# Callback to SWIG class C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, swig

I'm stuck with a problem with some SWIG bindings from C++ to Java. Basically, I call a binded class with a callback that I have extended in java. This is the idea:

```
binded.h
class callback {
public:
    virtual void f(){
        std::cout<<"Not implemented"<<std::endl;
    }
}
extern void create(callback *callback);
```

binded.h is wraped using SWIG into a java class following the usual procedure

```
%{
   #include "binded.h"
%}
%include "binded.h"
```

Then in java

```
public class ExtendedCallback extends callback
{
    public void f(){
         //code
    }
    public void run(){
        create(this);
    }
}
```

And the result of run() is "Not implemented". It seems like the extension of the function f is not being updated in the C++ wraped function which uses the "default" function.

According to what I have read in the SWIG documentation http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn30 Seems I need some way to tell SWIG that it will receive a class in the callback, but I can not see the way of doing it with a class instead of with a function like it is done in the documentation.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java part of SWIG use callbacks wrapping named directors: http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Java.html#java_directors

interface file will be something like:

```
%module(directors="1") modulename
%{
   #include "binded.h"
%}
%feature("director") callback;
%include "binded.h"
```